# How to define "compound entropy"

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory

[Entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) measures the "surprise" one experiences when uncovering a the actual value of a random variable as $$-\sum_i p_i \log_2 p_i$$

E.g., if we observe `Red` 8 times, `Green` 4 times, and `Blue` 4 times, and estimate the underlying probabilities from those observations, we say that the variable has entropy $$H(X)=\frac{1}{2}\times 1 + \frac{1}{4}\times 2 + \frac{1}{4}\times 2 = \frac{3}{2}$$

However, suppose that the information about `X` is supplied by several sources. How do I apportion these 1.5 bits of information among them?

E.g., suppose the source `Tulip` supplied `Red` 4 times and `Blue` 4 times, source `Daisy` supplied `Red` 4 times and source `Iris` supplied `Green` 4 times.

What is the value of each source to me?

Clearly `Tulip` is the most valuable (it produces half of the observations and all `Blue`s), `Iris` is the second (it produces all the `Green`s), and `Daisy` is the third.

EDIT:

A more formal setting is:

There is a random variable $X$ taking values from set $C$. 
It is observed together with "source" $S$ taking values from a smaller set $F$. 
I want to express the entropy of $X$ as a sum $\sum_s V(s)P(S=s)$ where $V$ is the "value" of the source $s$. 
The obvious condition on $V$ are: $V(s_1)>V(s_2)$ if $$H(X|S=s_1)P(S=s_1)>H(X|S=s_2)P(S=s_2)$$ or 
$$H(X|S\ne s_1)P(S\ne s_1)<H(X|S\ne s_2)P(S\ne s_2)$$

Comment: It seems to me that you have a problem with the definition of entropy itself: "If we observe Red 8 times, Green 4 times, and Blue 4 times, we say that the variable has entropy 1.5." No. If the source output is Red with prob. $0.5$, Blue with prob. $0.25$, and Green with prob. $.25$, then the entropy is $1.5$. You cannot assign "any entropy" given a finite number of observations. Also, better to say that entropy is a measure of uncertainty, I am not sure what do you mean by "surprise."

Comment: I do not fully understande the setting, I am sorry! Let $X\Omega:\rightarrow\{R,B,G\}$ be the random variable with outcomes "Red",...and probabilities given as in the OP. Moving to "Tulip" etc is equivalent to introduce a new variable $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\{T,D,I\}$, where the probabilities of the outcomes are computed using the rules you state. Is this what you mean with "...supplies... n times"?

Comment: @Avitus: yes, more or less

Comment: Then all you need is to compute the entropy $H(Y)$, as you have the probabilities associated to each outcome of $Y$, thanks to your "rules of supply". $Y$ and $X$ are even isomorphic, in this setting.

Comment: @Avitus: No, they are not isomorphic. Please see the edit.

Comment: I think you simply want the conditional entropy $H(X|S=s_1)$. If it is not, can you clarify? (the question is not super clear to me)

Comment: @Memming: I think $H(X|S=s_i)=0$ for both `Daisy` and `Iris` because then `X` takes just one value, but these sources are not worthless.

Comment: @sds they are worthless if you know which source it is. If you don't know the source, what you are looking for might be just Mutual Information. :)

Comment: @Memming: what are "they" that you deem "worthless"? And I do need the specific value of each individual source.