# How to define a utility of an information source?

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, utility

This is a more specific (and, hopefully, clearer version of a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591442/how-to-define-compound-entropy)).

The utility of discovering the value of a random variable $X$ can be defined to be its [information content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_content). 
When that value is discovered through an intermediate source $S$, one would want to apportion the utility among the possible values of the source, like this:
\begin{align*}
H(X)&=-\sum_i P(X=x_i)\log P(X=x_i)\\
    &=-\sum_i (\sum_j P(X=x_i,S=s_j))\log P(X=x_i)\\
    &=\sum_j -\sum_i P(X=x_i,S=s_j)\log P(X=x_i)\\
    &=\sum_j P(S=s_j) (- \sum_i P(X=x_i|S=s_j)\log P(X=x_i))
\end{align*}

which leads to the definition of utility of source $s_j$ for discovering $X$:

$$U(s_j,X)=-\sum_i P(X=x_i,S=s_j)\log P(X=x_i)$$

The nice properties of this definition include independence on $j$ when $X$ and $S$ are independent and the "intuitive monotonicity": for the example in the previous question, the utility of `Tulip` is 3/4, `Iris` is 1/2 and `Daisy` is 1/4 (the order is as expected).

Another thing which we can defined is the source quality(?):

$$Q(s_j,X)=-\sum_i P(X=x_i|S=s_j)\log P(X=x_i)=\frac{U(s_j,X)}{P(S=s_j)}$$

The question is: do these quantities have official names?